# Applying border and background image to Linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have linear layout in which i have to apply border,border radius and background image. I tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- $Id$ -->
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"   >

    <solid        
        android:color="#505050" >               
    </solid>

   <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#dddddd" >
    </stroke>

    <corners        
        android:radius="11dp" >        
    </corners>

</shape>
```

But i was unable to set background image in this xml. Please guide me.

Comment: What folder did you place this shape.xml in?

Comment: in your LinearLayout android:background="@drawable/shape"

Comment: then you should be able to use `android:background="@drawable/my_shape"` right in the `<LinearLayout>`, where "my_shape" is the name of your xml.

Comment: But i want to set background image(drawable/pattern.png) to my linear layout. Where should i add this.

Comment: the shape file should be xml, not png...? or is the png file different from the xml shown here?

Comment: simple: `<bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />`

Answer (score 2):

You can set the background either to an image drawable or a shape drawable. You cannot have both -- except if you make yourself a 9 patch image, which is actually quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

You have to place the background image in the "drawable-hdpi" folder which you should find it in your project's folder , this is first.

second; be careful once you name the image, Capital letters, space & sometimes dash & underscore, is not acceptable & makes errors. + don't add the extension of the image at all.

The final thing  :

```
<LinearLayout //whatever 
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >
```

Comment: This is ok. How can i set corner radius for the layout?

Comment: try this  [  android:radius="10dp" ]

Comment: @Sarah `android:radius` is not an attribute of LinearLayout's

Comment: @TronicZomB, oh, sorry I hate using the LinearLayout :p, thanks for the info :)

Comment: No big deal, just wanted to point that out. I've been "forced" to use them more since they are convenient at times compared to my fav RelativeLayout. lol

Answer (score 0):

Your `LinearLayout` will look like the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
        android:background="@drawable/my_shape"
        <!-- the rest of the attributes you want -->
        >

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @vignesh do you mean padding? like `android:padding="2dp"`?

Comment: No. <corners android:radius="11dp" ></corners> used in shape.xml

Comment: @vignesh that should be done in the shape.xml, not the layout xml. Doesn't the corner radius attribute show when you set the drawable to the background?

Comment: For corner radius i went for shape.xml, but there i cant set background image to my layout. If i set background image directly, i cant use shape.xml. How to achieve this both?

Comment: @vignesh oh! ok that makes sense. In that situation I think you will need to follow Ridcully's answer to achieve your desired look.